# How to test stream-based API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-5, networkstream

I'm developing internal messaging protocol that is based on TCP. Everything works, but I want to add tests to it.

It is possible to test serialization/deserialization with `MemoryStream`, but I can't find a way to test this thing as whole - with contiguous message interchange, because `MemoryStream` "*ends*" after reading first message.

The question: Is there a stream that behaves like `NetworkStream` (duplex, ends only when other end closed, can't seek) in base library or any nuget package?

Currently I can start 2 `TcpClient`s and use them, but I think it have too much overhead for tests especially when there's hundreds of tests running simultaneously

Comment: You can write to memory stream multiple times.  It is ending because you are only adding one message to the memory stream.

Comment: @jdweng from `System.IO.Pipelines` perspective it ends after `PipeReader` read to ends which `MemoryStream` have

Comment: A stream in Net has only one pointer so you can either read or write not both at same time like with linux.  When you read a stream you have to move the position to the beginning and then read.  If you then write when position is at position zero you are overwriting the old data.  There is no difference between a stream (memory stream) and a NetworkStream.  Both uses the same base class.

Comment: @jdweng I know how streams works and it's not what I'm asking for. I'm searching for implementation of stream where I can use something like `(Stream, Stream) GetPair()` and get 2 streams that I can read and write into

Comment: There is not pair.   Just open two separate streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've been looking for [Nerdbank.Streams.FullDuplexStream](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.Streams/blob/main/doc/FullDuplexStream.md)